# The file 'Google.Apis.Drive.v2.cs' was not found in a project

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I started a project two month ago, using Google Apis for accessing the files from my drive. I created a service account. This time, I was modifying some parts of the code and I had to re-install Google.Aps.Drive.v2 from Nu-Get Package Manager. Even trying it for many times I always got this error:

> "Locating source for 'C:\Users\cloudsharp\Documents\GitHub\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\Generated\Google.Apis.Drive.v2\Google.Apis.Drive.v2.cs'. Checksum: SHA1 {46 88 7f 6e f4 4f f8 2a e3 39 57 bb 41 2f b8 d1 3e e3 bd d9}
>   The file 'C:\Users\cloudsharp\Documents\GitHub\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\Generated\Google.Apis.Drive.v2\Google.Apis.Drive.v2.cs' does not exist.
>   Looking in script documents for 'C:\Users\cloudsharp\Documents\GitHub\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\Generated\Google.Apis.Drive.v2\Google.Apis.Drive.v2.cs'...
>   Looking in the projects for 'C:\Users\cloudsharp\Documents\GitHub\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\Generated\Google.Apis.Drive.v2\Google.Apis.Drive.v2.cs'.
>   The file was not found in a project.
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src\'...
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\'...
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\atl\'...
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\'...
>   The debug source files settings for the active solution indicate that the debugger will not ask the user to find the file: C:\Users\cloudsharp\Documents\GitHub\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\Generated\Google.Apis.Drive.v2\Google.Apis.Drive.v2.cs.
>   The debugger could not locate the source file 'C:\Users\cloudsharp\Documents\GitHub\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\Generated\Google.Apis.Drive.v2\Google.Apis.Drive.v2.cs'."

I only get this error while debugging the application, and not while executing it directly.
For the first time when I tried to communicate with Google Api services, I got the above error, and thus I added this below code:

`List result = new List();
FilesResource.ListRequest request = service.Files.List();`

And it follows but, now in the second line I am getting this error(mentioned in title).
I've searched in my project directory and I've found the Google.Apis.Drive.v2.dll, and it's added in References.

Comment: Sounds like the dll isn't installed correctly.    try and create a new project and include the nugget package again.   Looks like you were able to create the service so the other dlls should be ok its just the drive one that there must be something wrong with.  Try and right click it under references and see where it should be make sure its their.    you might want to try drive v3 btw.

Comment: Hello again. I proceeded as you adviced but the problem still remains. I've created another proyect and added the reference by the command
"Install-Package Google.Apis.Drive.v2" in NuGet Manager Console, then I added the files from the proyect and no error were found. If I execute the code nothing is wrong, but nothing happens, I mean no files from my drive are pulled. But if I debug I get the same error I've mentioned. I didn't want to migrate to v3 because it was working fine v2, but if there's no option left..  I'd thank you if you figure out some other idea.

Comment: I found out that if I use a client id (json) it works but that's for requesting the user a permission for accessing his drive's files, and with a service account it's not working (not retrieving files from my own drive), so it's not about the assembly as I guessed

Comment: Sounds like you made Oauth credentials instead of service account credentials. The code is also different for service account

Comment: yes, that was the problem! I've made service account credential for the first time, but as it hadn't worked, I changed to Oauth credentials. Now I could fix it by storing the response in my proyect and copying it in the storage drive of responses. I've found a new problem now, but I'll start the topic apart. Thank you for everything and sorry for my english, i'm from Argentina.